# Setting shortcut for equal sign in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way I can set a shortcut for equal sign in VSCode. Let's say I want `command+J` to print out `=`.

Comment: its not vscode but you can do it with autohotkey https://www.autohotkey.com/

Comment: @jonathanHeindl Thanks but autohotkey app is windows only (Im macOS) and I don't think it's a good idea to install a whole new app just for one keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put this in your keybinding.json

```
    {
        "key": "cmd+j",
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "args": {
            "snippet": "="
        }
    }
```

Comment: clikc on the settings wheel -  keyboard shortcuts and then click on the link below the search bar

Comment: `editor.action.insertSnippet` was new to me. Thanks.